# how to secure a valuable stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption

This question might not be perfect for this platform but I trust people here a lot.

I am coding a data transfer application for an ERP system, many people create C# projects that are slow, not flexible and full of errors. I found a way to do it in SQL SERVER with Stored Procedures. But I dont want my SPs to be stolen by any programmers since SPs are kind of open source. I create my SPs with encryption but I found a small application on the internet which can show the content of SPs.

Is there any other way of encrypting and securing my SPs in sql server?

Comment: Of course, they should contact with me. That is the point. If I had done an C# app, they would contact with me since they cannot see the inside of the app

Comment: @SQLPolice, what if he copies my sql and send to many companies.Then, I would get bankrupted. Also, why do you think that .Net Developers give binary to their customer, instead of the source code. It is business

Comment: pointless discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your application *entirely* written in Stored Procedures with no other code? How likely do you think it is that someone really will want to steal your code? I only ask because usually, if someone wants the code badly enough, they will find a way to get it. If they will go so far as to [counterfeit an entire Apple store](http://www.tealeafnation.com/2013/06/chinas-copycat-phenomenon-fake-apple-stores-booming-in-southern-china/) then someone can always crack any encryption scheme.

The best way to protect your intellectual property (i.e. the code) is to simply not give it to anyone: host it as a service. Outside of that obvious, simple, yet not always possible option, here are some things to consider:

1. For T-SQL stored procedures you can certainly deter the lower-end thieves by using the built-in encryption. Yes, you found a way to decrypt it by searching around, but not everyone will do that or know what to look for. This is not much of a barrier, but again, it is a very easy step that weeds out folks who are just poking around.
2. You can put some of your code into SQLCLR (i.e. .NET C# or VB via SQL Server's "CLR Integration" feature/API), though this won't work for everything, nor would it be a good choice to do for everything. But, for any code that would be more efficient to do in SQLCLR then it would be even harder to get the source code of the Assemblies. Again, not impossible, and there are free tools out there to decompile Assemblies, but this does raise the bar a bit as someone would have to extract the Assembly to a DLL and then decompile it (though I believe one tool will extract it from SQL Server, but still harder to come by than "how to decrypt an encrypted Stored Procedure"
3. With regards to .NET code (definitely for stand-alone app and possibly also for SQLCLR code), it is also possible to obfuscate the Assemblies such that it is very difficult, at best, to decompile it. There are products such as Red-Gate's [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) that can do this.
4. Be better than your competition:

   1. Innovate and offer better features (i.e. a better product). Listen to customers and make their lives easier. Even if someone does end up getting your code, they can't steal you. Stolen code might teach them something, but it is essentially stagnant compared to what you should be producing.
   2. Offer better service. Be personable and answer questions thoroughly, respectfully, and with a smile (even silly / stupid questions--if you need to, vent to a friend, but never in writing). Sure, some customers decide to purchase purely on price, but service/support is usually a large factor in both getting and *retaining* customers.

So, if you can find a quick and easy means of doing this then great. But don't spend too much time on it when your time is better spent improving your product. Besides, unless you came up with some highly complex algorithm, most things can be reverse-engineered, if they are smart enough. But if the folks you are worried about were that smart, would their software be "slow, not flexible and full of errors"? And along those same lines, (and just to have it stated), the other software being "slow, not flexible and full of errors" has nothing to do with them being written in C# (especially not the "not flexible and full of errors" issues): they simply just aren't written well ;-).

Comment: I agree with you. A better service is much more valuable than a piece of code. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way, simply use the option `WITH ENCRYPTION` in your sp's definition.

**Example**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spEncryptedProc
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
END
GO
```

Now try to see the definition of that procedure.....

```
exec sp_helptext 'spEncryptedProc'

Result: The text for object 'spEncryptedProc' is encrypted.
```

Make sure you personally have a copy of the stored procedure saved somewhere else you cannot see the procedure definition yourself.

Comment: You only forgot to mention that this encryption is, of course, reversible. There is no protection against a DBA in SQL Server.

Comment: `WITH ENCRYPTION` is easily reversible.